# Broken Java 3D Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, 3d

I am trying to draw a 3D tile grid that can be rotated and elevated.

The grid though, when rotated sometimes, does not show the graphics as it should, and mutilates them. The regular grid should look nothing like this.

The top half should not be present.

[image]

Can anyone help explain or give examples as to what may be causing this issue?
Just found something else: When you see the spike appear, on one side of your screen, on the opposite, that tile is missing. :

[image]

Comment: @Legend What, specifically, is the "mutilation" you see? I compiled and ran your code fine, but I didn't see anything particularly egregious.

Comment: @CajunLuke The mutilation, which is highly visible for 100 X 100 grids, makes it almost unbearable to use. It creates almost a parallel grid above the original.

Comment: Heh, if you had to create that output, it'd take extra work. :) Anyway, the update is _great_, upvoted. :)

Comment: @Legend I was at work, so I looked at it for about thirty seconds. I'm glad you have several good answers now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that if you set `azimuth` to 133, `elevation` to 324, `zmod` to -0.9, leave `xmod` at 0 and change the grid to 7 × 7 instead of 10 × 10, then only one single point 'misbehaves'.  For this one misbehaving point, we have:

- `i` = 48, `j` = 3,
- `x0` = 7.0, `y0` = 0.0, `z0` = 6.1,
- `x1` = -0.31273127, `y1` = 5.4544506, `z1` = -7.5074077,
- `near` = 6.0 and `nearToObj` = 1.5,

just before the following two lines:

```
            x1 = x1 * near / (z1 + near + nearToObj);
            y1 = y1 * near / (z1 + near + nearToObj);
```

The critical thing here is that `z1 + near + nearToObj` has crossed below zero.  As it crossed below zero, it caused the sign of the values of `x1` and `y1` calculated by the above two lines to change.  This sign change is what causes the grid to appear wrong.

I'm no expert in 3D graphics, but I believe this outcome suggests that you can't plot the point in question because it has gone behind the camera.  I'm afraid I'm not sure what the best way to solve this problem would be - that would require more knowledge of 3D graphics than I have.

---

As for my other answer, it was totally wrong, so I've deleted it.  If I was going to claim that the Java 2D graphics API was any doing wrapping using 16-bit integers, I could at least have tried to verify that

```
g.drawLine(30, 30, 60, 60);
```

and

```
g.drawLine(30, 30, 60 + 65536, 60 + 65536);
```

produced the same output.  They do not.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but sorry to kinda forget to say this, but I made a simple onScreen method to check to see if any of the x and y point locations for each tile are on screen, if not it doesn't print. This fixed the problem.

Thank you for your huge amount of effort into this, and I hope this gets thumbed up a lot.

Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

What's `(new BasicStroke(6 / 5))` supposed to do?

`6 / 5` is a fancy way to write `1`.

```
$ cat Int.java
class Int {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("6 / 5 == " + (6 / 5));
        return;
    }
}
$ make Int.class
javac Int.java
$ java Int
6 / 5 == 1
$
```